# Saving text into a list from Azure

Tags: java, android, azure, android-studio

I have made an application where the user enters text into a textbox  which gets sent up to azure once a button is clicked. Once the user clicks the button they are taking to a separate java activity where the text from the textbox is added to a listbox. However once I close the app or change screen the text is not saved into the listbox permanently even though it is saved in the Azure. Can anyone help me to add the text from azure to my listbox permanently. The listbox is on my ListDeadlines activity.

My Code is as fallows

AddDeadline Activity

```
 private MobileServiceClient mClient;
private EditText title;
public EditText editText;
public EditText editDate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_deadline);

    try {
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "https://craigsapp.azure-mobile.net/",
                "BTkcgnFQvevAdmmRteHCmhHPzdGydq84",
                this
        );
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   final ListDeadlines lst= new ListDeadlines();

    lst.txtInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinput);

    ImageView btAdd=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    btAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            title= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtinput);

            Item item = new Item();
            item.Text = title.getText().toString();
            Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("result", item.Text = title.getText().toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            mClient.getTable(Item.class).insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<Item>() {
                public void onCompleted(Item entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                    if (exception == null) {
                        // Insert succeeded
                    } else {
                        // Insert failed
                    }
                }
            });
            finish();
        }
    });
```

ListDeadline Activity

```
public ArrayList<String> arrayList;
public ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public ArrayAdapter<String> newad;
public EditText txtInput;
public EditText txtDate;
public int ADD_DEADLINE_REQUEST=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_deadlines);
    final ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listv);
    String[] items= {""};
    arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.txtitem,arrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Item newitem = new Item();
    if (requestCode == ADD_DEADLINE_REQUEST){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String item = data.getStringExtra("result");
            arrayList.add(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Deadline has been added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 100, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to query azure for the text and then populate your listbox. Or if you want to save the text locally then you can do it using shared preferences.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Is there anyway you could give me an example on how to do this as I'm new at android development. Thanks

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm an example to help you with remembering the text locally on your phone. http://hayageek.com/android-http-post-get/ this shows you how to get a response from a particular website - http post/get

Comment: I'm trying to get my table and the insert it into my listView like this. Would something like this be possible `MobileServiceTable<Item> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(Item.class);
        lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mToDoTable));`

Answer (score 0):

As @pooja said, you can try to get the text via query Azure Mobile Service or get from the local storage. However, for keeping consistent between local and cloud, you need to add Offline Data Sync to your Android Mobile Services app, please see the offical document https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-get-started-offline-data/.

There are two demo video below.

1. https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-155-Offline-Storage-with-Donna-Malayeri
2. http://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/videos/azure-mobile-services-offline-enabled-apps-with-donna-malayeri/ (For Windows, but feature discussion applies to all platforms.)

And an Android sample for offline data sync on GitHub you can refer to, please see https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/tree/master/TodoOffline/Android.

Comment: I'm trying to get my table into the listView would something like this be possible `MobileServiceTable<Item> mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(Item.class);
        lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mToDoTable));`